# Text Field with action (button) on the left or right in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am not able to have a button inside a text field

```
   <v-text-field
      outlined 
      label="Other items"
      color="primary"
      >
      <template v-slot:append>
        <v-btn
          depressed 
          tile
          color="white"
          class="ma-0"
          @click="deleteTypedItem(index)">
          <v-icon  color="grey">clear</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
```

by the above code, I am getting like this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Text fields are not a placeholders of other widgets/components

Comment: @Begueradj but he could add clearable prop or append the clear icon as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: I thought he wanted to place a button inside a text field

Answer (score 1):

```html
<v-text-field
      outlined 
      label="Other items"
      color="primary"
      append-icon="mdi-close"
      @click:append="deleteTypedItem(index)" 
      >
    </v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Clearable

```
<v-text-field
      outlined 
      label="Other items"
      color="primary"
       Clearable
       @click:clear="clearCustomer"
      >
    </v-text-field>
```

Note: icon only visible text entered in field otherwise icon hidden